# How is this related to the geometric law?

Tags: probability

Assume we have $2^n$ possible outputs but only one of them is the right answer.
On average we need $2^n$ attempts to get the right answer.
Why is that and how is it related to the geometric law?

Comment: @Alex The number of successes in a fixed number of trials is binomial. The expected number of trials needed for a success is geometric.

Answer (score 1):

If you have probability $p$ of success and you keep running independent trials and stop when you succeed, then the probability of succeeding after $n$ trials is the same as the probability of failing $n-1$ times in a row and then succeeding; that is, $$(1-p)^{n-1}p,$$ i.e. the number of required trials is geometrically distributed. Then the expected value of number of trials is

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}p
\end{align*}

To see that this is $1/p$, we can apply an identity. In general we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}x^{n} \\
&= \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}1/(1-x) \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align*}

for $|x| < 1$. Letting $x = 1-p$,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}p &= p/(1 - (1-p))^2\\
 &= p/p^2\\
&= 1/p.
\end{align*}